# Chrome: How do I modify a font stack for all websites that use that stack using a script?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, fonts

Many websites (especially coding- and development-related ones), including StackOverflow, use the *--apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI"...* system font stack, which I am not fond of, since I have a Windows computer and Segoe UI looks jagged in several cases. I recently downloaded the new Segoe UI Variable font family included in Windows 11, and since it looks much smoother, I want to replace Segoe UI with Segoe UI Variable Small (one of the three styles of Segoe UI Variable) on all websites that use the above system font stack.

Currently I use the Stylus Chrome extension to manually set the font to Segoe UI Variable Small, but I need to do this for every individual website that uses the system font stack, on every CSS class, and beyond a point it gets tiring to keep adding websites to the user styles. Is there a way to write a script in TamperMonkey or similar to automatically replace Segoe UI with Segoe UI Variable Small on all websites that use this font stack, **but not any others**?

Answer (score 1):

I think a chrome extension would do since it has more capabilities. Userscripts in my opinion are designed for more specific things. Usually Userscripts are aimed at one particular website that they want to execute there code on instead of putting the same code on many many websites. Such thing is better with chrome extensions. Write an extension that just scans for anything with segoe UI but keeps out segoe ui variable small and replaces the scanned segoe ui to the variable small one. This would change many of the websites but for some websites you would need to be more specific in a way.